# Terminal services and memory limits

Tags: memory, terminal-server

Is there a way in Terminal Services to set limits on memory related parameters for a process. For example working set size and, possibly, if it makes sense, total virtual memory allocation for the session?

To turn the question around, we have an application which cannot allocate as much virtual memory running on a terminal server as it can when running on a desktop PC (both I would expect to have a limit of 2GB for user mode address space) and I was wondering if there is another limit for processes or users on a terminal server. Perhaps even 2GB per user rather than per process.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not much you can do to limit the amount of memory a process claims in Windows using nice graphical interfaces, unless the process itself has some tuning parameters.

One option could possibly be to write your own program that is started with the terminal server login that limits all processes for a user using [Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) objects, which is the windows API for this kind of things.